# JS: How to correctly use await for an asynchronous GraphQL data fetch within an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, apollo-client

I'm currently working on a project where I have an asynchronous function, `fetchSomeData`, which internally makes a call to an asynchronous GraphQL data fetching function, `fetchGraphQLData`. The `fetchGraphQLData` function returns a promise containing data, loading status, and potential errors.

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client';

const DEFAULT_URI = 'https://example.com/graphql';

const getGraphQLClient = (uri = DEFAULT_URI) => {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri,
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  return client;
};

export default getGraphQLClient;
```

```js
export const fetchGraphQLData = async <T,>({
  query,
  variables,
}: QueryOptions): Promise<TQueryResult<T>> => {
  const { data, loading, error } = await getGraphQLClient().query<T>({
    query,
    variables,
  });
  return { data, loading, error };
};
```

I'm wondering if using `await` for the `fetchGraphQLData` call is necessary in this context, or if there's a more efficient or best-practice way to handle this scenario.

```js
const fetchSomeData = async (): Promise<TQueryResult<TSomeData>> => {
    return fetchGraphQLData<TSomeData>({
        query: someQuery,
    });;
};
```

Can someone shed some light on the correct usage of await in this context and any potential pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: What is `getGraphQLClient` doing?

Comment: The `{ data, loading, error }` return value of your `query` method looks like this is a React hook, not a promise-returning function that you could `await`.

Comment: @Bergi The `getGraphQLClient` function is a utility function for creating and configuring a GraphQL client using the Apollo Client library in JavaScript.

Comment: The `{ data, loading, error }` are returns values from the query method. Here's the interface: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/a7859e6a9f8f42f1520720d241ed3010d3384b7f/src/core/types.ts#L142

Comment: Thank you, @AndyRay, for sharing this post with me. I'm still going over it, but it's helpful so far.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the clarification, so you are using https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient#query. Notice that returning `loading` is pointless, it'll always be `false` in this usage.

Comment: Notice that all the destructuring is pretty pointless, unless you want to explictly exclude other properties. Your `fetchGraphQLData` function could be simplified to just `export const fetchGraphQLData = <T,>(options: QueryOptions): Promise<TQueryResult<T>> => getGraphQLClient().query<T>(options);` - at which point you may wonder whether you need this at all. Imo you should just directly call `getGraphQLClient().query(…)` from `fetchSomeData`.